# Most sensitive GPS receiver module during cold start

Tags: gps

I've looked at u-blox, telit, Simcom and Quectel.

The best receiver from cold start I've found so far is from Telit at -148dBm for acquisition (cold start).

e.g. [telit jupiter se868](http://www.telit.com/products/product-service-selector/product-service-selector/show/product/jupiter-se868-v3/)

Has anyone come across a GPS module with a better cold start sensitivity?

> Cold Start is performed every time when the GPS module is turned off
>   without backup power supply connected. It is the longest starting time
>   out of the three and usually takes 35 seconds in average under open
>   sky environment. During Cold Start, almanac and ephemeris data has to
>   be downloaded first from the GPS satellites to GPS module before a
>   position fix can be acquired.

Comment: What do you mean by cold start?

Comment: A cold start is when the receiver must acquire the satellite location from scratch. http://www.gtop-tech.com/en/faq/4.9.-What-differentiate-between-Cold-Start-Warm-Start-and-Hot-Start/GPS_Module_Design-4_9.html

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by sensitivity? Are you concerned about accuracy during those 30ish seconds during locating the device? If not, I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. What's to goal of the hardware? Is there a reason you can't wait for the location once cold start is completed?

Comment: Sensitivity means that the receiver can receive a signal that has a power of -xdBm, in the case of Telit SE868 that is -148dBm, (1.5848931925e-18 watts).  3dBm represents a power doubling, (approximately).  So there is a big difference between -148dBm an -145dBm.  The later is twice the power.  A good GPS receiver means that you can find a GPS signal even in built up area where the may be overhead obstructions.